# c# ToString method for XSD Generated Class

Tags: c#, xsd

I have a class generated using XSD.exe but I would like to have a ToString method for this object so I can add them to list boxes etc. I may have to regenerate these classes in the future from the XSD files so I do not want to manually override the method on the generated class. Is there a way around this without creating a new class?

My generated class looks like this; I want a ToString method to display a few of the class variables not the name of the class which it is currently doing.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.1432")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class cardOnFileResponse {

    private string paymentInstrumentRefField;

    private string partyIdField;

    private string friendlyNameField;

    private string cardholderNameField;

    private string maskedPANField;

    private string startDateField;

    private string expiryDateField;

    private string issueNoField;

    private cardType cardTypeField;

    private bool cardTypeFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string paymentInstrumentRef {
        get {
            return this.paymentInstrumentRefField;
        }
        set {
            this.paymentInstrumentRefField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string partyId {
        get {
            return this.partyIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.partyIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string friendlyName {
        get {
            return this.friendlyNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.friendlyNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string cardholderName {
        get {
            return this.cardholderNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.cardholderNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string maskedPAN {
        get {
            return this.maskedPANField;
        }
        set {
            this.maskedPANField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string startDate {
        get {
            return this.startDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.startDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string expiryDate {
        get {
            return this.expiryDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.expiryDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string issueNo {
        get {
            return this.issueNoField;
        }
        set {
            this.issueNoField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public cardType cardType {
        get {
            return this.cardTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.cardTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool cardTypeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.cardTypeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.cardTypeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's generated as a partial class you can have a separate partial class that you create (not auto-generated) in which you override ToString().
e.g.

```
public partial class cardOnFileResponse 
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Response: {0} {1}", this.friendlyNameField, this.cardholderNameField);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for the hint. A quick read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/wa80x488.aspx explains this well.

Answer (score 1):

It is already declared as a partial class so in a separate file define ToString():

```
public partial class cardOnFileResponse {
    public new string ToString()
    {
        string retn="";
        retn += ....
        return retn;
    }
}
```

Of course, if the generated code removes or changes fields you use in your ToString() implementation, you may need to update it.